# How to upload an image in strapi to the collection type fields?

Tags: javascript, strapi

I have created a collection in strapi with name **Events**.

**Events** have fields like **id**, **Event_image** and **Event_title**.

The **Event_image** is media and **Event_title** is text.

The events are created by adding value to the **Event_title** field but no image uploaded in **Event_image** field.

Here, I want to upload image using strapi API for specific event in the **Events** collection.

I have used **upload** API from strapi where I pass parameters such as:

files: The image file to be uploaded

refId: The field id of the event where file needs to upload (id)

ref: The collection name (Events)

field: The field Event_image of event where image needs to upload (Event_image)

**Below is the code:**

```
 function uploadImage() {
       const data = new FormData();
       data.append('files', this.state.imageFile]);
       data.append('refId', 1);            
       data.append('ref', 'Events');
       data.append('field', 'Event_image');
       axios.post("http://1.0.0.0:xxxxx/upload", data)
       .then(function(response) {
          console.log(response)
       })
    }
```

The above API return **Internal Server Error**.
Please let me know if I am missing something which is not letting it work or I am doing something wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not exactly sure what you trying to do...
With strapi you need first to upload images as files to content folder and then you add file-url to image-field (Event_image).
If your image is small, you could decode it to base64 and then you could save it straight to the database.

Comment: I am trying to upload image using API call and not directly on CMS.

Comment: You can’t store images in the strapi database (at least not with default functionality). Images and other files should be stored on disk and then you add url to that file to your image-field. If you are using Heroku or similar service provider, you can’t store your files to heroku’s disk, because it will be wiped clean regularly. Use amazon S3 or other file server.

Comment: Not true you can upload a file at entry creation with Strapi: https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/plugins/upload.html#upload-file-during-entry-creation

Answer (score 0):

The ref should be

> api::modelName.modelName

so in your case,
ref = "api::events.events"